Killing fields and tangent vectors in symmetric spaces.
I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ be a symmetric space.

Show that for every tangent vector $v \in T_x X$ there exists a one-parameter group of transvections $t\rightarrow p_t^v$ so that $\frac{d}{dt} p_t^v(x)|_{t=0} = v$.
Each of the one-parameter group of transvections $p_t^v$ as in the first part determines a Killing field $X(v)$. Show that the vector space of Killing fields of this from is a linear subspace of the vector space of all Killing fields.
In the case that $X=S^3$, determine explicitely its dimension and codimension in the vector space of all Killing fields.


My solution is as follows:

Let $X$ be a symmetric space. By definition, for any $x \in X$, there is an involutive isometry $s_x: X \to X $ such that $x $ is an isolated fixed point and $ s_x$ reverses geodesics through $x$. Given a tangent vector $v \in T_x X$, we want to construct a one-parameter group of transvections $p_t^v$ such that $\frac{d}{dt} p_t^v(x) \big|_{t=0} = v$.
Transvections in a symmetric space are compositions of symmetries. Specifically, for each pair of points $x, y \in X$, the transvection $p_{xy}$ is given by $p_{xy} = s_y \circ s_x $.
Consider a geodesic $\gamma(t)$ in $X$ such that $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0) = v$. For each $t$, define $p_t^v$ as the transvection along the geodesic: $ p_t^v = p_{\gamma(t)x}$. This gives a one-parameter family of transvections. The crucial property is:
$p_t^v(x) = \gamma(t).$ and taking the derivative with respect to $ t $ at $ t = 0 $ we obtain: $ \frac{d}{dt} p_t^v(x) \big|_{t=0} = \dot{\gamma}(0) = v. $

Consider the set of Killing fields generated by transvections:
$ \mathcal{K} = \{ X(v) \mid v \in T_x X \}.$
We need to show that $\mathcal{K} $ is a linear subspace of the vector space of all Killing fields.
For $v, w \in T_x X $ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R} $, we consider the combination $ aX(v) + bX(w)$ and calculate:
$(aX(v) + bX(w))_y = a \frac{d}{dt} p_t^v(y) \big|_{t=0} + b \frac{d}{dt} p_t^w(y) \big|_{t=0}. $
Since the sum of derivatives of isometries is again a derivative of an isometry $aX(v) + bX(w)$ is still a Killing field. Therefore, $\mathcal{K}$ is a linear subspace.

For $X = S^3$, the dimension of the space of all Killing fields corresponds to the dimension of the Lie algebra of the isometry group $SO(4)$, which is 6-dimensional. The space of Killing fields generated by transvections is associated with the tangent space at a point, which is 3-dimensional. Thus, for $S^3$, the dimension of the subspace $\mathcal{K}$ is 3. The codimension in the space of all Killing fields (which is 6-dimensional) is therefore $3$.


Assuming, 1. and 2. are correct, is this reasoning what was meant by "explicitely" in 3. ?
